# Clarifying the use of maxReportLatencyUs in SensorManager.registerListener

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

[From the latest documentation,](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int,%20int%29)

> **boolean registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, 
>                   Sensor sensor, 
>                   int samplingPeriodUs, 
>                   int maxReportLatencyUs)**
>
> Registers a SensorEventListener for the given sensor at the given sampling frequency and the given maximum reporting latency.
>
> This function is similar to registerListener(SensorEventListener, Sensor, int) but it allows events to stay temporarily in the hardware FIFO (queue) before being delivered. **The events can be stored in the hardware FIFO up to maxReportLatencyUs microseconds. Once one of the events in the FIFO needs to be reported, all of the events in the FIFO are reported sequentially.** This means that some events will be reported before the maximum reporting latency has elapsed.
>
> When maxReportLatencyUs is 0, the call is equivalent to a call to registerListener(SensorEventListener, Sensor, int), as it requires the events to be delivered as soon as possible.
>
> When sensor.maxFifoEventCount() is 0, the sensor does not use a FIFO, so the call will also be equivalent to registerListener(SensorEventListener, Sensor, int).
>
> **Setting maxReportLatencyUs to a positive value allows to reduce the number of interrupts the AP (Application Processor) receives, hence reducing power consumption, as the AP can switch to a lower power state while the sensor is capturing the data.** This is especially important when registering to wake-up sensors, for which each interrupt causes the AP to wake up if it was in suspend mode. See isWakeUpSensor() for more information on wake-up sensors.

Assuming the system respects to `samplingPeriodUs` and the sensor uses a FIFO,

1. Is the actual report interval of `registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000, 200000)` 400000us?
2. Can `registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000, 190000)` reduce the number of interrupts the AP (Application Processor) receives, hence reducing power consumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you compute 400000us?

The samplingPeriodUs is the period when the sensor stores a sample in the hardware FIFO (Just a hint but typically values sensed within a small variation) without waking up the CPU.

The maxReportLatencyUs is the interval when the sensor delivers the stored samples to the listener by calling onSensorChanged() repeatedly in a burst. It is necessary for the sensor to be a wake-up sensor or the wakelock is held in ahead before reporting.

Therefore to your questions,
A1: Every 200000us, you may get one reported sample in the event.
A2: Every 190000us, it is reported only if there are stored samples. Since your maxReportLatencyUs < samplingPeriodUs, there could be no reporting for no samples in the FIFO. So yes, the CPU is notified nearly every 190000us and can sleep in the interval.

Comment: 1. I think that the report latency timer of the hardware FIFO starts only when the FIFO has a sample, and stops when the FIFO flushes. Therefore I guess the actual report interval is 400000us.
It seems that you suggest the FIFO flushes every maxReportLatencyUs. The timer won't stop even when the FIFO has no samples.
Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: 2. Why registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000, 190000) can reduce power consumption but registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000) cannot? The number of interrupts the CPU received should be the same, since the CPU is notified only if there are stored samples and  both reports a sample each time.

Comment: Nope, it starts soon after the listener is registered and is PERIODICAL until the listener is unregistered. If there are no samples in the FIFO, this time reporting is simply skipped.

Comment: For power consumption, you need to consider how a wakelock is held during sensing. If the sensor you get is not of wake-up type and your app do not acquire the wakelock, the device goes to sleep and there is no reporting of the samples until the user or other apps wake up the device.

Comment: If the sensor you get is of wake-up type, the sensor driver acquires the wakelock to deliver the report in the intervals such that your device can sleep in between. That implies your device can sleep for the maxReportLatencyUs and only wake up in a short burst of reporting. This saves power consumption because longer device idle prevents other apps to start processing and consume the battery even though your app may consume similar CPU cycles.

Comment: So if I register a wake-up sensor, the device wakes up every maxReportLatencyUs even when there are no samples to receive. registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000) holds the wakelock until the listener is unregistered.

Comment: Not even when but only when there are samples in the FIFO to deliver.
registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000) wakes up the device every 200ms to deliver a sample by holding the wakelock if the sensor is wake-up.

Comment: Then there is not much difference in power consumption between registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000, 190000) and registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000). The former wakes up the device every 190000us if there are samples in the FIFO, and the latter wakes up the device every 200000us.

Comment: This is because registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000) = registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000, 200000). It makes little sense to set both to a similar value. So the catch is whether the sensor is of wake-up type. Also, if your app has a deadline constraint, choose the values wisely to maximize the power savings.

Comment: Correction: registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000) = registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000, 0) means to report ASAP. registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000, 190000) might get you to wait for one more reporting interval to deliver the samples compared with  registerListener(listener, sensor, 200000).